# How do I solve this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\displaystyle \large \cos 2x + 1 - \sin 2x=\frac{2 \cos 2x \cos x}{\cos x + \sin x}$

I've been trying for a long time but I can't get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\cos 2x + 1 - \sin 2x  = (\cos x + \sin x)(\cos x - \sin x) + (\cos x - \sin x)^2 $$

$$ = (\cos x - \sin x)(2 \cos x) = \frac{2 \cos 2x \cos x}{\cos x + \sin x}$$

Seems to be an identity.

So all you need is $\cos x + \sin x \neq 0$ and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Using the identities 
$$
 {\cos 2x=\cos^2 x -\sin^2  x},\quad  \cos 2x=2\cos^2 x-1,\quad \sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x
$$
We have, if $\cos x+\sin x\ne0$
$$\eqalign{
{2 {\cos 2x} \cos x\over \cos x+\sin x}
&={2(  {\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x}) \cos x\over \cos x+\sin x}\cr
&={2(\cos x+\sin x)(\cos x-\sin x) \cos x\over \cos x+\sin x}\cr
&={2 (\cos x-\sin x) \cos x }\cr
&=2\cos^2 x -2\sin x\cos x\cr
&=\cos 2x +1 -\sin 2x.
}
$$